# using sed command to read between sections in a given file

Tags: text-processing, sed

File content.

```
[kafka_properties]
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:KAFKA_CLIENT_PORT
default.replication.factor=2
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.cipher.suites=["TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",]
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSV1.2
ssl.secure.random.implem=SHA1PRNG
security.inter.broker.protocol=PLAINTEXT
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https


[kafka_ports]
KAFKA_CLIENT_PORT=9082

[zookeeper_properties]
clientPort=ZK_CLIENT_PORT
syncLimit=2
initLimit=5
tickTime=2000
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
admin.serverPort=ZK_SERVER_ADMIN_PORT
```

I am trying to read the values from every section, e.g. `[kafka_properties]`, or `[kafka_ports]` using this command:

```
cat file.txt | sed -n '0,/kafka_properties/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p'
```

And write the values into a different file. It works okay if I don't add the parameter:

```
ssl.cipher.suites=["TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",]
```

but after adding the `ssl.cipher.suites=` parameter to the `file.txt` sed is not working as expected.
Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how sed is "not working as expected". What output were you expecting and what output do you actually get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `[` only match at the beginning of the line with `^`:

```
sed -n '0,/kafka_properties/d;/^\[/,$d;/^$/d;p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, writing each section to a different file without needing to know the section names, you could do:

```
awk '/^\[/{n=$1;gsub(/[][]/,"",n)}{print >> n".txt"}' file
```

This will create these files from your example:

```
kafka_ports.txt  kakfa_properties.txt  zookeeper_properties.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `/^\[/{n=$1;gsub(/[][]/,"",n)}` : if this line starts with a `[`, save the 1st field as the variable `n` and remove all `[` or `]` from it.
- `print >> n".txt"` : append the curent line to the file `n.txt` where `n` is the name of the section.

Note that this assumes you never have whitespace in a section name. If you do, try this instead:

```
awk '/^\[/{n=$0;gsub(/[][]/,"",n); gsub(/ /,"_",n)}{print >> n".txt"}' file
```